# HOC pass through properties

Tags: reactjs

I'm lately struggling with complex HOC and how I can pass through only the new props defined in it and not any other.
More precisely, suppose my HOC makes use of other HOCs which extends its properties, for instance

```js
const withSession = (WrappedComponent) => {

  class SessionProvider extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.login = this.login.bind(this);
    }

    login() {
      console.log('login'); // this will dispatch some action
      // this.props.dispatch... 
    }

    render() {

      return (
        <WrappedComponent
          doLogin={this.login}
          {...this.props} 
        />
      );
    }
  }

  const mapStateToProps = null;

  function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
      dispatch,
    };
  }

 const withConnect = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps);

 return compose(
    withConnect,
    withRouter,
  )(injectIntl(SessionProvider));
};
```

Here the `SessionProvider` makes use of `dispatch` and `injectIntl` which attach properties to its `props`. However, I don't want to pass those props down to the wrapped component. The idea is to have a `SessionProvider` HOC which has some API call but only extends the wrapped component with `login`.
I noticed that if keep `{...this.props}`, the wrapped component will also get all the `props` used by the HOC which I don't want to pass through. 
So I thought to explicitly define which properties to pass through by decomposing `this.props` by changing the HOC render method:

```js
render() {
  const { dispatch, intl, ...otherProps } = this.props;
  return <WrappedComponent doLogin={this.login} { ...otherProps} />;
}
```

However what happens with this is that if the WrappedComponent itself has `dispach` or `intl` props, those are not passed-through the HOC.

Is there anything wrong in what I'm doing? Any better approach? Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong in what you're doing. Prop name conflicts is a known issue when using HOCs. So, as far as I can tell, the best alternative you could use is **[Render Props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html)** pattern, which helps to keep components `render` as declarative as possible. For your case, consider something like this:

```
class Session extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.login = this.login.bind(this);
  }

  login() {
    console.log("login"); // this will dispatch some action
    // this.props.dispatch...
  }

  // ...

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {this.props.children({
          doLogin: this.login
          doLogout: this.logout
          // ...
        })}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

// ...

return compose(
  withConnect,
  withRouter
)(injectIntl(Session));
```

And use it from another components:

```
// ...
render() {
  return (

    <Session>
      {({ doLogin, doLogout }) => (
        <React.Fragment>
          <SomeComponent doLogin={doLogin} />
          <button onClick={doLogout}>Logout</button>
        </React.Fragment>
      )}
    </Session>

  )
}
```

**UPDATE:**

There's a pretty promising **[Hooks Proposal](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)** available in **v16.7.0-alpha**. I'm not quite familiar with them yet, but they tend to solve components reusability more efficiently.

Comment: I went for Render Props solution, thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy static properties, for that i use below code.. you can add more properties as per your need

```
export const REACT_STATICS = {
  childContextTypes: true,
  contextTypes: true,
  defaultProps: true,
  displayName: true,
  getDefaultProps: true,
  mixins: true,
  propTypes: true,
  type: true
};

export const KNOWN_STATICS = {
  name: true,
  length: true,
  prototype: true,
  caller: true,
  arguments: true,
  arity: true
};

export function hoistStatics(targetComponent, sourceComponent) {
  var keys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(sourceComponent);
  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; ++i) {
    const key = keys[i];
    if (!REACT_STATICS[key] && !KNOWN_STATICS[key]) {
      try {
        targetComponent[key] = sourceComponent[key];
      } catch (error) {}
    }
  }
  return targetComponent;
}


// in HOC
const hoistedSessionProvider = hoistStatics(SessionProvider, WrappedComponent);

// use hoistedSessionProvider in compose
```

Comment: Yes, I had the same idea but I used the component `propTypes` to pass through the HOC only the props it needs